# Spring boot and logstash tcp link dosent work with docker compose "localhost/<unresolved>:5000"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, logstash

It works for me in local but i had an error when using **docker** :

error is :   localhost/<unresolved>:5000: connection,
how can i set this unresolved value for **logstash** destination id

`docker-compose`

```
 version: '3.2'
    services:
      elasticsearch:
        image: elasticsearch:$ELK_VERSION
        volumes:
          - elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        environment:
          ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
          # Note: currently there doesn't seem to be a way to change the default user for Elasticsearch
          ELASTIC_PASSWORD: $ELASTIC_PASSWORD
          # Use single node discovery in order to disable production mode and avoid bootstrap checks
          # see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html
          discovery.type: single-node
          # X-Pack security needs to be enabled for Elasticsearch to actually authenticate requests
          xpack.security.enabled: "true"
        ports:
          - "9200:9200"
          - "9300:9300"
        healthcheck:
          test: "wget -q -O - http://$ELASTIC_USER:$ELASTIC_PASSWORD@localhost:9200/_cat/health"
          interval: 1s
          timeout: 30s
          retries: 300
        networks:
          - internal
        restart: unless-stopped
      # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/docker-config.html
      logstash:
        image: logstash:$ELK_VERSION
        ports:
          - "5000:5000"
          - "9600:9600"
        environment:
          LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
          ELASTIC_USER: $ELASTIC_USER
          ELASTIC_PASSWORD: $ELASTIC_PASSWORD
          XPACK_MONITORING_ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME: $ELASTIC_USER
          XPACK_MONITORING_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD: $ELASTIC_PASSWORD
          XPACK_MONITORING_ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: "elasticsearch:9200"
          XPACK_MONITORING_ENABLED: "true"
        volumes:
          - ./logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline:ro
        networks:
          - internal
        restart: unless-stopped
        depends_on:
          - elasticsearch
    
      # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/docker.html
      kibana:
        image: kibana:${ELK_VERSION}
        environment:
          ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME: $ELASTIC_USER
          ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD: $ELASTIC_PASSWORD
          # Because Elasticsearch is running in a containerized environment
          # (setting this to false will result in CPU stats not being correct in the Monitoring UI):
          XPACK_MONITORING_UI_CONTAINER_ELASTICSEARCH_ENABLED: "true"
        ports:
          - "5601:5601"
        networks:
          - internal
        restart: unless-stopped
        depends_on:
          - elasticsearch
          - logstash
      mysqldb:
        image: mysql:5.7
        restart: unless-stopped
        env_file: ./.env
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=$MYSQLDB_DATABASE
        ports:
          - $MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT:$MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT
        volumes:
          - db:/var/lib/mysql
      app:
        depends_on:
          - mysqldb
        build: ./../
        restart: on-failure
        env_file: ./.env
        ports:
          - $SPRING_LOCAL_PORT:$SPRING_DOCKER_PORT
        environment:
          SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
            "spring.datasource.url"  : "jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:$MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT/$MYSQLDB_DATABASE?useSSL=false",
            "spring.datasource.username" : "$MYSQLDB_USER",
            "spring.datasource.password" : "$MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD",
            "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect" : "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect",
            "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" : "update",
            "spring.application.name" : "ebnelhaythem"
          }'
        volumes:
          - .m2:/root/.m2
    
    networks:
      internal:
    
    volumes:
      elasticsearch:
      db:
```

AND LOGS ARE :

```
elastic_log_docker-app-1            | 14:15:45,959 |-WARN in net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender[logstash] - Log destination localhost/<unresolved>:5000: connection
         failed. java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        elastic_log_docker-app-1            |   at java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        elastic_log_docker-app-1            |   at      at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
        elastic_log_docker-app-1            |   at      at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
```

Comment: Do you have something configured in your Spring application, but not in the Docker configuration, to forward logs to `localhost` (that is, the Spring application container)?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes probably, you can found the project here for more details https://github.com/azzabihaythem/ebnelhaythem/tree/master/elastic_log_docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Spring Boot application expect `logstash` to be available at `localhost`:

```yaml
logstash:
  host: localhost
```

However, when you run everything inside docker-compose, logstash will *not* be present at `localhost` since this now *refers to the app container*.

To resolve this, override the [logstash host property](https://github.com/azzabihaythem/ebnelhaythem/blob/562d75182b432ca33b1ffc9273ebdbab027327f3/src/main/resources/application.yml#L16) when you run the application with docker-compose with the value `logstash` (so the name of the docker-compose service). Similar as you do for the MySQL url.

Comment: yes good point , i fixed this but i got the same error  :"Log destination logstash/<unresolved>:5000: connection 
failed" now :(

Comment: It is because there are _two_ networks in the `docker-compose` file. 

The `internal` network used by ElasticSearch, Kibana and Logstash services and the `default` network used by the app and mysql service.

These two network are isolated form each other and hence the host `logstash` is not resolved.

Either remove:
`networks:  - internal`
from the above services or add mysql + app to also use the internal network.